# Hibernate subclass with a set property, how do I separate the set property to a different class for which there is a table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have Product hbm in which I have multiple sub-class, but for one subclass I have  property and the set property has a composite element..so I want to have a primary key in the composite element..Is there any way I can do that? I tried segregating the set as a new outside but it fails with the error that the key column cannot be inserted null...

The code is as below:

```java
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class lazy="false" name="com.dummy.products.bizobjects.Orderable"
        table="PROD_ORDERABLE">

        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="ID" unsaved-value="null">
            <meta attribute="scope-set">protected</meta>
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <discriminator column="ORDERABLE_TYPE" type="string"
            length="64" not-null="true" force="true" />

        <property name="orderableType" type="string" insert="false"
            update="false">
            <meta attribute="use-in-equals">true</meta>
            <meta attribute="scope-set">protected</meta>
            <column name="ORDERABLE_TYPE" index="IDX_PROD_ORDERABLE"
                unique-key="name_version_option_type_rev" length="64" />
        </property>

      //this is the subclass
        <subclass name="com.dummy.products.bizobjects.LicensedProduct"
            discriminator-value="bo.constants.orderable.type.licensedProduct">
            <meta attribute="generated-class" inherit="false">com.dummy.products.entities.LicensedProductData</meta>
            <meta attribute="scope-set" inherit="false">protected</meta>
            <meta attribute="scope-class">public abstract</meta>

///This is the code before hand....and below set I tried converting to class further below
           <!--  <set name="licensedItems" table="PROD_ORDERABLE_BUNDLE" cascade="all"
                lazy="true">
                <meta attribute="field-description">
                    The list of licensable items within this
                    orderable, if it is of type licensedproduct.
                </meta>
                <meta attribute="scope-set">protected</meta>
                <meta attribute="implement-equals">true</meta>

                <key column="ORDERABLE_ID" />
                <composite-element class="com.dummy.products.bizobjects.LicensedItem">
                    <meta attribute="generated-class" inherit="false">com.dummy.products.entities.LicensedItemData</meta>
                    <meta attribute="extends">com.dummy.platform.entities.Entity</meta>
                <meta attribute="implements">com.dummy.platform.bizobjects.IMarkTimestampable</meta>
                    <property name="count" column="BUNDLE_COUNT" type="int" />
                    <many-to-one name="bundle"
                        class="com.dummy.products.bizobjects.FeatureBundle" column="BUNDLE_ID"
                        index="PROD_IDX_ORD_FBUNDLE">
                        <meta attribute="use-in-equals">true</meta>
                        <meta attribute="scope-set">protected</meta>
                    </many-to-one>
                </composite-element>
            </set> -->

            //this is the conversion of above set
            <set name="licensedItems" table="PROD_ORDERABLE_BUNDLE" cascade="all"
                lazy="true">

                <key column="ORDERABLE_ID" />
                  <one-to-many class="com.dummy.products.bizobjects.LicensedItem"/>
            </set>


    </class>
    //the new table which will get created should have three columns : ORDERABLE_ID, ID,BUNDLE_COUNT,BUNDLE_ID
    //when ever I am trying to save it gives error cannot insert null value in ORDERABLE_ID which is the key column
    <class lazy="false" name="com.dummy.products.bizobjects.LicensedItem" table="PROD_ORDERABLE_BUNDLE">
            <meta attribute="class-description">
              The list of licensable features within this
                    orderable, if it is of type licensedproduct.
            </meta>
            <meta attribute="generated-class" inherit="false">com.dummy.products.entities.LicensedItemData</meta>
            <meta attribute="scope-class">public abstract</meta>
             <meta attribute="extends">com.dummy.platform.entities.Entity</meta>
              <meta attribute="implements">com.dummy.platform.bizobjects.IMarkTimestampable</meta>

            <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="ID" unsaved-value="null">
                <meta attribute="scope-set">protected</meta>
                <generator class="native"/>
            </id>
              <property name="count" column="BUNDLE_COUNT" type="int" />
                <many-to-one name="bundle" class="com.dummy.products.bizobjects.FeatureBundle" column="BUNDLE_ID"
                 index="PROD_IDX_ORD_FBUNDLE" >
                        <meta attribute="use-in-equals">true</meta>
                           <meta attribute="scope-set">protected</meta>
                    </many-to-one>
        </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

I want to convert set inside a subclass to a new class as I want a primary key in the mapping table PROD_ORDERABLE_BUNDLE